# Unable to install Pandas in Python 3.4 on Win 7 64bit

Tags: python, pandas, windows-7

I used following process to install:

1. Download & install 64-bit `Python`: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/
2. Download the 64-bit version of `numpy`:
3. `pip install "numpy-1.9.2rc1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl"`
4. `pip install pandas==0.14.0`

Error message is attached. 
Thank you for help. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtCA1.jpg)

Comment: install from `pip install package` , why are you installing specific wheel package unless you are 100% sure thats the one your system needs?

Answer (score 0):

When you intstall pandas it will automatically install numpy so need to install numpy seperately, also you need to have microsfit visual basic C++ 10.0.

I had the same case and when I installed it everythig went fine.